# How to check enum values exists using dlsym?

Tags: ios, unix, dlsym

[`dlsym`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/dlsym.3.html) returns null for enum values

```
NSLog(@"%s",dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "NSTextAlignmentCenter"));
```

Output

```
2014-01-28 13:07:04.243 TestProject[763:60b] (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum values are an "integer constant expression". They don't have a reference.